# How to detect append build mode on Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, post-processing

Currently working with [PostProcessBuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) on Unity. I'm writing into a generated XCode project (iOS build). On iOS platform, there is two builds : replace and append. Replace will build the project erasing the previous copy, Append will replace only the files that are different.

The issue is that on "Append" build, the PostProcess is also called, resulting in duplicate PostProcess code.

My only workaround is to check if the code already exists in the file, but it demands a lot of unecessary work (knowing that I'm in "Append" build will avoid to compare files !).

Do you have any ideas to detect append mode ? Unity documentation is quiet about that.

Comment: What o you mean by "append mode"? Is there any where it can be set from the Editor?

Comment: how about you create your own build process, it's easy to setup and you could have 2 different builds types, one that writes the code and one that doesn't. It might sound like a lot of work but i promise it's not, you could have your own build process up and running in 5 mins. look into UnityEditor.BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.

Comment: @Programmer I think he means, when you make a build for iOS, you have the option to either Replace or Append the output to the existing folder. Replace will format the folder and make a new build, Append will keep the existing files and add only new/changed ones. It is visible in the Editor only once you click on build and select the desired folder, and there is a project there already.

Comment: @Hristo yes, that's exactly the point, I edited the question to be clear about that. The Append mode is a build option on iOS. Making my own build process is also a good idea, but in my case, in can't do this as this is a part of a plugin : I can't expect a custom build process from the user.